# Mongoose read-only without schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose in my node.js app to model two collections in the database, which it will read and write. There are two more collections which are going to be read only from my app (the model for these collections is being maintained in another app, which will write to them).

If I need to access the two read-only collections using mongoose, then I will have to maintain a schema within this app as well. I would rather not do this as the schema will be maintained twice and could lead to inconsistency later on.

The default connection in Mongoose can be created by

```
Mongoose.connect(dbPath)
```

Given a dbPath (e.g. `mongodb://localhost/dbname`), how can I use the Mongoose default connection to read from a collection whose schema/model is not being maintained by my app? Or will I have to use the native MongoDB driver for the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're just using Mongoose to read from a collection, you can leave the schema definition empty.

So if you had a read-only collection named `test`, something like this will work:

```
var Test = mongoose.model('Test', new Schema(), 'test');
Test.findOne({name: 'John'}, function(err, doc) { ... });
```

Or for better performance, include [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) in your query chain if you don't need any of the model instance functionality:

```
Test.findOne({name: 'John'}).lean().exec(function(err, doc) { ... });
```

If you don't use `lean()` you need to access the properties of the doc using the [`get`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get) method; for example:

```
doc.get('name') // instead of doc.name
```

Comment: When you use the model in this way, how can you reference one of the properties of the resulting doc? Using dot-notation is giving me undefined errors.

JSON.parse returns "unexpected token _"

Comment: I'm a bit new to Mongoose but this seems like a design flaw to me. Why require a schema if it is not necessary for reading from an existing collection. I had a situation where one system defined and populated a collection and another system (only) read from it. The second system passed in a schema to `model()` which wasn't complete but it didn't seem to matter, which was confusing. It seems to me that the involved mechanisms could have been more clearly defined.